# How can I interrupt a blocking method in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking, break, sigint

Usually I can interrupt stuff with Ctrl+C, but sometimes when I'm using threads it doesn't work - example below.

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep(100)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
K    eyboardInterrupt
>>> import Queue
>>> q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=3)
>>> q.put(0)
>>> q.put(1)
>>> q.put(2)
>>> q.put(3)
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C

^C^C^C

^C^C
^C
@*#()#@#@$!!!!!
```

**edit:**  Is there a way to get back to the interpreter?  Solutions so far kill python completely and your existing namespace ..

Comment: This seems to be specifically a threading issue; Ctrl-C works just fine to interrupt, for example, `raw_input()`.

Comment: Only the main thread gets signals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can kill the Python interpreter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

This will send a `SIGQUIT` instead of `SIGINT`.

Comment: Not if he has a stock Ubuntu system.

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ Oops, you're right, I accidentally included a totally wrong shortcut (that explains the rofl from Matt). Don't know where my mind was. Back *slash* terminates python, alt+Back *space* terminates X.

Comment: thanks .. will the same thing happen behind the scenes if i just shut the terminal window?  (oh look, a canberran!)

Comment: @wim No, that will send a `SIGTERM` and/or `SIGKILL`. In practice, unless you messed with [signal interception](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html), the effect will be the same though.

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround for ^C failing is suspending the process with all threads first with ^Z and then killing it.

This works in Linux for many cases when ^C fails, and as I've just tested it works here too (tested on Python v.2.6.5):

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) [GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Queue
>>> q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=3)
>>> q.put(0)
>>> q.put(1)
>>> q.put(2)
>>> [^C]
KeyboardInterrupt #does not kill the process
>>> [^Z - Suspends and exits to shell]
[1]+  Stopped                 python
#mdf:~$ kill -9 %%
[1]+  Killed                  python
```

Answer (score 0):

A lazy way to do this is to open another window.

Do `ps` to get the PID.

Do `kill` to kill the offending process.